# How do I Locate/Specify the Size of Pooling Layers in Caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, mnist

My team has been going through Caffe's MNIST Example and has been able to locate/specify the number of neurons/filters in some of the neural network's layers (like the convolution layer) which is referred to by a parameter called num_output.
However, the pooling layers don't seem to specify the number of outputs they have/we can adjust.
Is there any way to locate this information so that I can be able to know how many neurons exist in each layer of the MNIST example neural network?

In addition, the 1st convolution layer has num_output = 20 and the 2nd convolution layer has num_output = 50. How is this jump in layer depth made? I would assume it's because of the pooling layers between convolution layers 1 and 2 but again I do not understand how many filters the pooling layers have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that pooling layer is a special kind of layer which main purpose is to decrease a dimensionality of output from convolutional layer.

The output of pooling layers is a function of its parameters - kernel size, pad and stride, as well as size of the output from a convolutional layer. With width `W` and height `H` of kernel, pads `Ph, Pw`, and strides `Sh, Sw` it produces an output from a convolutional layer of a size `Wc x Hc x Dc` which has :

1. `Width = (Wc + 2 * Pc - W) / Sw + 1`
2. `Height = (Hc + 2 * Ph - H) / Sh + 1`
3. `Depth = Dc`

You can read a detailed explaination of parameters [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html) and details of pooling operation [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#pool).

Comment: So the pooling layer takes into account its parameters and the dimensions of the convolution layer before it and uses them to specify its own dimensions, yes?
But if the pooling layer decreases the dimensionality of convolutional output, how is it that the net goes from convolution layer1 (size 20) --> pooling layer --> convolution layer2 (size 50)? Thanks.

Comment: Num_out is number of filters. It might be set to an arbitrary number. The designer of a network set it to 50 and this is the reason why the size is as it is :)

Comment: Okay. I understand much better now. Thank you!